# How to create long time socket in background android

Tags: java, android, background-service

I want to create custom push notification service with socket programming.
The problem I have is that I want the socket to be constantly active in background. But all my background services are disabled after the app is killed. I also do not want to use foreground service. Do you have a solution?

Manifrest:

```
<service android:name="com.example.app.CustomNotificationService">

</service>
```

Serivce:

```
class CustomNotificationService : Service() {

   override fun onCreate() {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        super.onCreate()
   }

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        Thread{
            while (true){
                Thread.sleep(10000)
                mHandler.post {
                    toast("a")
                }
            }
        }.start()
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
        startService(Intent(this@MainActivity,CustomNotificationService::class.java))
```